# Google Search API with joomla

Tags: api, search, joomla

I would like to implement the google search API in a joomla site. What would be the best way to pass the search query and show the results inside of my templates content area. Making a custom component or there is a lighter workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try [RokAjaxSearch](http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokajaxsearch) as I believe this has the ability to display results from Google. And above all, it's Ajax, therefore doesn't refresh the page.

Hope this helps